# After using pivot_wider(), values from `Column A` and `Column B` are not uniquely identified; How can I get one value per column?

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have the following issue:
I have a table in the longer format )with about 8000 IDs and even more dates):

```
ID     Testdate    Medication    MedicationATB
1      2022-01-01  Atrovent      33AT
1      2022-01-01  Ventolin      22BB
1      2022-01-02  Amlodipin     33CC
2      2022-01-02  Torem         77FA
2      2022-01-01  Prednsiolon   11MM
3      2022-07-07  Dafalgan      24BB
3      2022-08-08  Aspirin       23AA

df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Testdate = c("2022-01-01", 
"2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-01", "2022-07-07", 
"2022-08-08"), Medication = c("Atrovent", "Ventolin", "Amlodipin", 
"Torem", "Prednsiolon", "Dafalgan", "Aspirin"), MedicationATB = c("33AT", 
"22BB", "33CC", "77FA", "11MM", "24BB", "23AA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
7L))
```

I am interested in getting the medications when they are first recored (e.g. 2022-01-01), and on the last day (e.g. 22-08-08), but none of the medications in between.
When I convert it into the wider format I have the issue that there are non unique events which is expected since one can use multiple medications at the same time.

My code is the following:

```
df1 <- df%>%
pivot_wider(id_cols=ID, names_from = Testdate, values_from =c(Medication, MedicationATB))
```

The output is as follows:

```
ID    Medication_2022-01-01          Medication_2022-01-02   MedicationATB_2022-01-01   Medication_2022-01-24
1     Atrovent, Ventolin             Amlodipin               33AT, 22BB                 
2     Prednisolon                    Torem
```

The ideal output would allow me to count and name each specific medication on the first and last day of observation.
I have not figured out how to split the multiple variables so I get one variable per column and row.
I am not sure if using the wider format is the best option therefore.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: First and last recorded per ID (patient) or for the whole group?

Comment: You say "count and name each specific medication", but your attempt does not count. What is your _exact_ desired output? For all users in this sample data, your "none of the medications in between" means nothing since all `ID`s have precisely two dates of data, but to be clear, if ID=1 has something on `2022-01-03`, then we would discard `Amlodipin` completely, right?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not beeing precise enough: it would be the first and last recorded date per ID (patient) and adding I have some IDs with 20 dates.  The exact desired output would be something like this:

Comment: ID Medicationfirstdate Medicationlastdate MedicationATBfirstdate  edicationATBlastdate 1   Amlodipin                NA                          33CC                               NA 1 Atrovent             Atrovent                        33AT                        33AT

Comment: Please add the desired output structure to your question (the formatting gets lost in the comment). You can paste the output of `dput(desired_structure)` or use table markdown from any online generator: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 0):

using your example data, something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  summarise(first_date = min(Testdate),
            last_date = max(Testdate),
            .by = c(ID, Medication),
            ) |>
  mutate(meds_per_ID = n(),
            .by = ID
            )
```

output:

```
  ID  Medication first_date  last_date meds_per_ID
1  1    Atrovent 2022-01-01 2022-01-01           3
2  1    Ventolin 2022-01-01 2022-01-01           3
3  1   Amlodipin 2022-01-02 2022-01-02           3
4  2       Torem 2022-01-02 2022-01-02           2
5  2 Prednsiolon 2022-01-01 2022-01-01           2
6  3    Dafalgan 2022-07-07 2022-07-07           2
7  3     Aspirin 2022-08-08 2022-08-08           2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but not exactly what I have been looking for, see my comment above, and sorry for the missing precision in my earlier description.